# How to link a wordpress custom post with its types?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

So I have to export custom post ie portfolio from one site to new site which has the new theme. I was able to import custom post and its types but the imported custom post is not linked to the categories. Is there a plugin which will do this automatically for me? if not, please direct me to the resources which will help me do so. Thanks!

Comment: Just export the database and import it with the new website.

Comment: that did not work, i have new database with many things than the previous site